# SDL2 without X: No available video device

Tags: c, linux, sdl-2

I'm looking for а way to build a lightweight system whitout X to be able run SDL2 full-screen application on Intel CPU with integrated video. I have minimal debian 9 (netinst) system. i965-va-driver was installed and SDL2 was built from sources in accordance with [this article](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/22/raspberry-pi-raspbian-getting-started-sdl-2/). Any errors was not issued. SDL_Init() in my simple application returns error "No available video device". Talking about supported drivers on "configure" step discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36572003/6028542). Does anybody know how to configure SDL2 correctly and install right driver?

Comment: If the system is *headless* then that means it will not have a monitor or keyboard/mouse connected to it. So it doesn't use the on-board video or need a driver for it. What it does mean is that you should be able to log on remotely to the machine, and then run graphical applications over the network. For Linux this is usually done by installing X11 client libraries on the headless system, and an X11 display server on your local system, and then set the `DISPLAY` to connect to your local X11 server. If you connect over SSH also do some research about *ssh x11 tunneling*.

Comment: Sry. I think I asked my question a little bit incorrectly. I mean my system has no X.

Comment: There might be other ways to connect remotely and display a GUI over a network, but X is the most common and best supported way to do it. I strongly advice you to consider it (the X11 client libraries aren't that big, if that's your worry).

Comment: I *think* [DirectFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectFB) is close to what you're looking for. I've had success using it with SDL2 on a Raspberry Pi, but it has been a while so I don't remember the details.

Comment: @Quentin While DirectFB is good for embedded systems, it's a way to display graphics *locally* and not over a network connected to a headless system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh. The "headless" part had disappeared from the question.

Comment: @Quentin Ah, okay. Then DirectFB is definitely the way to go for small embedded systems (where X is overkill).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, guys! I'll try DirectFB. PS: My hardware platform is not Raspberry, it based on small Intel CPU.